# php дубликаты в цикле как объединить

Tags: php, foreach

подскажите, как объединить или отсортировать дубликаты в цикле?

```
$q = "SELECT route_short_name, ...... FROM stop_bus WHERE route_id = $statement->routeId";
$res = $link->query($q);
foreach ($res as $row)
{
    $rs = $row['route_short_name']; //это поле выводит номер транспорта
```

как удалить дубликаты я знаю

выводится примерно в таком виде

25,
203,
25 - дубль (разные значения)
11,
30,
11 -дубль (разные значения)

а мне нужно собрать

25,25,203,30,11,11

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk а где здесь "исходный массив"?

Comment: Миша. А как насчет того чтобы отсортировать строки *в запросе*?

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk в $res **не массив**

Comment: мне не нужна сортировка по убыванию возрастанию, мне нужно их скомпоновать по одинаковым номерам